# Distance between two objects given their angle of depression

Tags: trigonometry, angle

> A boat is situated between a lighthouse and a ship such that all three of them are in a straight line. If the angles of depression of
> the boat and the ship from the top of the lighthouse $20$ meters
> above sea level are $30$ degrees and $15$ degrees respectively. What is the distance between the boat and ship?

I did $20\tan(75^\circ) - 20\tan(60^\circ)$ which gave me $40$ meters and I am not sure if it's correct since the instructions said round your answer in hundredths.

Comment: This is a very typical IGCSE Cambridge CIM extended math problem. I suggest you take a look at some past papers for it, they practically have hundreds(pretty sure) of these kinds of questions. Look at their paper 4's.

Comment: Your calculations are correct.  Just express your answer in the form $40.00~\text{m}$.